# How to rewrite a nested loop with Reap and Sow

Tags: code-review, performance-tuning

I was wondering if anyone know how to rewrite the following nested loop but using Reap and Sow. I need to reduce the execution time. Thank you.

```
list = {};
AbsoluteTiming[
 Do[
  AppendTo[list, {}];
  If[i > 10,
   AppendTo[list[[i]], {}];
   ]
  , {i, 1, 10^4}]
 ]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. But you can get the same answer like this: `list = ConstantArray[{{}}, 10^4]; list[[1 ;; 10]] = {};` in far less time.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not well posed because it is predicated on a misconception that `Reap` and `Sow` are the appropriate tools to do what you wish to accomplish. bill s, rightly ignoring the constraint you place on the solution, has given a method which is both fast and simple.

On my system, your code

```
list = {};
First @ AbsoluteTiming[
  Do[
   AppendTo[list, {}];
   If[i > 10, AppendTo[list[[i]], {}];],
   {i, 1, 10^4}]]
```

gives 0.711651 seconds. bill s' code

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[
 list = ConstantArray[{{}}, 10^4]; list[[1 ;; 10]] = {};]
```

gives 0.000102 seconds. Both methods build the same list.